# How to resume debugger without stopping process when it says "Frames not available for unsuspended thread"

Tags: android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea

Can't resume debugger in Android Studio/Intellij IDE when Frames says: "Frames not available for unsuspended thread".

Resume button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the steps to reproduce and your IDE version that we can fix the issue. If the issue is Android specific, the better way to report it would be per https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html.

Comment: Issue reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-276554